# Open sets and metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

First off I am new to working with balls in metric spaces
so my might seem dumb to those who know better than I
I don’t want to down voted cause of it

Ref:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2124668/585321
In this proof r=0.5d(x,y). My question can the constant be 
smaller than it and prove the theorem

And in general is it possible?

Comment: How come it can’t be smaller. I don’t understand. In reproving Theorem 27 it seems to work Unless it is a completely different matter

Comment: What exactly is the question? I don't see one.

Comment: The question is what happens in r=kd(x,y) if k<0.5  Kavi states it cannot be. I read on PhysicsForum.com dealing with  balls and metric spaces that 1/2 makes the proof easier and occasionally allows sets to be disjointed (a definite plus)  .I won’t make any suppositions after since I seem to be choking on them

Comment: I think Kavi mis-interpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

The object is to prove in a metric space that points are closed, by showing that the complement of a point is always open.

So if $(M, d)$ is a metric space and $x \in M$, we want to show that $M \setminus \{x\}$ is open. Suppose $y \in M, y \ne x$. Then $d(x, y) > 0$.

Let $r$ be *any number* satisfying $0 < r \le d(x,y)$. Then $x \notin B_r(y)$, the open ball of radius $r$ about $y$. This is because $B_r(y) = \{z \in M\mid d(y,z) < r\}$, but $d(x,y) \ge r$. Hence $B_r(y) \subseteq M - \{x\}$.

Since $M - \{x\}$ contains a ball around each of its elements, it is open, and its complement $\{x\}$ is closed.

---

The value of $k$ used in $r = kd(x,y)$ can therefore be any number in $(0,1]$. szw1710 for some reason decided to prove that $y$ had a ball that was bounded away from $x$, which isn't actually necessary for this problem (but is true for any $k < 1$). They just used $r = \frac 12 d(x,y)$ as a convenient choice. Afterall, they just needed one value that worked, not every possible value.

Comment: So k<1/2 and work ? I actually deleted one part of the question. I redid Theorem 27 from set theory and metric spaces by kaplansky with letting r=1/3 . Letting r=1/3 didn’t seem to violate the theorem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but I don't own a copy of Set Theory and Matric Spaces by Kaplansky, so I have no idea what Theorem 27 in it is. Word of advice - always state the theorem you are talking about, instead of giving a reference to it that most people will not have access to. Another word of advice, you can find the basics of using mathjax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), so you can know that the element sign is `\in` and not have to use the Euro symbol as a substitute.